# Ajuda com PDO usando MySQL

Tags: php, sql, pdo, conexão

Estou com problemas para conectar o banco de dados utilizando PDO, uso o MySQL.

quando executo a conexao com o banco aparecem as seguintes mensagens de erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message ' in C:\wamp64\www\phpCRUD\config\Conecta.php on line 11
>
> PDOException: in C:\wamp64\www\phpCRUD\config\Conecta.php on line 11

Não sei onde estou errando, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Segue o código da configuração do banco:

```
<?php
    require_once 'conf.php';
    class Conecta extends conf{
        var $pdo;
        function __construct(){
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->host.':dbname='.$this->db, $this->usuario, $this->senha);
        }
        function login($email, $senha){
            $stmt = $this->PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = :email AND senha = :senha");
            $stmt->bindValue(":email",$email);
            $stmt->bindValue(":senha", $senha);

            $exec = $stmt->execute();
            $run = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return self::$run;
        }
    }
```

conf.php

```
<?php
    class conf{
        var $host = 'localhost';
        var $usuario = 'root';
        var $senha = '';
        var $db = 'hoo';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está fazendo uma pequena confusão com o atributo `$pdo` e a classe `PDO`

Na criação do atributo `$pdo`, não utilize var, utilize desta forma:

```
private $pdo;
```

Agora que você já têm seu atributo na classe, vamos atribuir a ele uma instância da classe PDO do php, então no construtor faça assim:

```
$this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->host.':dbname='.$this->db, $this->usuario, $this->senha);
//Atributo $pdo recebe uma instância da classe PDO
```

O `prepare` desta forma:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = :email AND senha = :senha")
```

No retorno também utilize desta forma, caso você queira que te retorne um array associativo com todos os valores da consulta

```
return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo Felipe Nascimento. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!